# Equivalence relation in dual spaces

Tags: dual-spaces

Do the dual spaces satisfy equivalence relation? 
For example the dual space of $\mathbb{R^n}$ is $\mathbb{R^n}$. Do the remaining two properties of equivalence relation can be applied to dual spaces, in general.
that is,

$Reflexivity, Symmetry, Transitivity$.

Note: The dual space of $l^1$ is $l^\infty$. Can the dual space of $l^\infty$ be $l^1$?

I don't have any clue about the generalization of these properties.
Any efforts will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: The dual space of $\Bbb R^n$ is not $\Bbb R^n$, it is the space of linear maps $\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ and happens to be isomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: more briefly it can be written as the dual space of $\mathbb{R^n}$ is $\mathbb{R^n}$ due to the homomorphism property.

Comment: look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space

Comment: $X$ dual of $Y$ does not imply $Y$ dual of $X$,$X$ dual of $Y$ and $Y$ dual of $Z$ does not imply $X$ dual of $Z$, and $X$ is its own dual (up to isometric isomorphism) in some special cases (e.g. Hilbert spaces).

Comment: For infinite-dimensional normed spaces this is false: the dual of $X$ is $Y$ implies the dual of $Y$ is $X$.  So the term "dual" becomes misleading in that setting...  Some people may therefore prefer to say "conjugate space" and not "dual space".

Comment: so the dual space of $l^\infty$ can be $l^1$?